# Rails 3.1 - Filling in Forms with Values

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-forms

I have two models:

```
# User.rb:
has_many :currics, :dependent => :destroy

# Curric.rb
belongs_to :user
```

A User has the following fields associated with it:

- Full Name
- E-mail
- City
- Postcode

In the form for creating a "Curric" I want to be able to find out if this information is already set, and if it is, don't display the section of the form.

However, if it isn't set (only Full Name and Email are required at signup), I want to render a section of the form to allow the user to save these fields, making sure that "Full Name" and "Email" fields will remain uneditable.

Does anyone have any idea how I would do this?

Cheers.